# isEqualToString Malfunction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Okey, I have two strings containing numbers like shown here using debugger:

**String 1**

```
(gdb) po [event creator_id]
123456789
(gdb) p [event creator_id]
$1 = (NSString *) 0xad81d10
```

**String 2**

```
(gdb) po [delegate userid]
123456789
(gdb) p [delegate userid]
$2 = (NSString *) 0x7451b40
```

Now I want to check if they are equal to each other and therein lies the problem.

The if-statement below will for some reason not return true:

```
if ([[delegate userid] isEqualToString: [event creator_id]]) {

    NSLog(@"They are equal!");

}
```

Can someone please explain to me how this can happen? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Is there a possibility of trailing space?

Comment: Is [[delegate userid] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] == YES  && [[event creator_id] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] == YES

Comment: Double-check there's no white space or invisible characters, maybe?

Comment: double-checking! gimme a sec!

Comment: @MSK It seems that [event creator_id] isnt really an NSString. But why does it show up in debugger as one if it really isn't? A failed cast that didn't result in an error??

Comment: po is "print-object" it prints the description (which is string) of object. The description property is available at NSObject level.

Comment: Added these comments as answer to your question :)

Comment: @MSK It seems that I had managed to set [event creator_id] which appears to be an int, to be an nsstring without getting any errors. And in debugger is would still show as an nsstring. Its seems strange to me that it would let me do that. Yeah I was just about to ask you to do that :) Thanks!

Comment: BTW this is the correct way NSString * creator_id_Str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[event creator_id]];

Comment: @MSK Yeah I know:). Already fixed it:) Its just that Facebook isnt very consistent in their API. The ID for a user is a string, but the id for the creator of an event turned out to be an int. Thanks anyways :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be because either of below is FALSE

```
[[delegate userid] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]

[[event creator_id] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]
```

po is "print-object" it prints the description (which is string) of object. The description property is available at NSObject level.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Many methods return an `id` that can be assigned to any `NSObject` pointer without generating a compiler error or warning. And the gdb "p" command uses only the type information generated from the source code and does not determine the actual class  at runtime.

Example:

```
NSString *s;
s = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Hello World"];
```

In the debugger:

```
(gdb) po s
<__NSArrayI 0x8ec70a0>(
Hello World
)

(gdb) p s
$1 = (NSString *) 0x8ec70a0
```

So "po" knows the actual class, but "p" does not.